# Kendo Grid with client CRUD, cancel remove row, can not set the ID properly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid in a form with editable information and I would like the information save with one submit. It has CRUD functions and it is inline editable. All the save and edit works fine. However, whenever I add a new row->update->edit->cancel, the row got removed.

There is a lot of articles say that it is the ID issue of each record. I add the
    `e.model.set('id', newId); e.model.set('CommentsID', newId);`
in the SaveEvent, but it doesnt get changed. I looked one of the post in stack, one of them has the same issue:

[Kendo UI MVC inline client-side grid - clicking cancel removes row. Not the model ID issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169879/kendo-ui-mvc-inline-client-side-grid-clicking-cancel-removes-row-not-the-mode)

But there are two issues for me(maybe I am wrong):

one is the Guid that it generates is converted to string while my CommentsID is an int; Second, which the one that I mentioned above, I can not change the value of a model using `e.model.set()`.

Since the only information I care about is the comment, I am wondering if there is any way that I can put a dummy ID to make it work so that the Cancel button won't remove the row when it is editing.

I also checked several links, but still didn't see any good solution.

Here is my code for the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<EE.BusinessLayer.ProviderLogic.POCO.CommentPOCO>)Model.Comments) 
.Name("Comments")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.CommentsID).Hidden();
    columns.Bound(c => c.ModifiedDate).Title("").Width(300).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format(\"{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}\",kendo.parseDate(ModifiedDate))#" + "<br> #=UserName#");
    columns.Bound(c => c.Comment).Title("").EditorTemplateName("TextAreaTemplate").ClientTemplate("<div style='max-width:465px;'>#=Comment#</div>").HtmlAttributes(new { style="max-width:470px;"});
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
})
.Events(e => e.Edit("editEvent").Save("saveEvent"))
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Comment"))
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .Model(m => {
        m.Id(p => p.CommentsID);
        m.Field(p => p.CommentsID);
        m.Field(p => p.ProviderID).Editable(false);
        m.Field(p => p.ModifiedDate).Editable(false);
        m.Field(p => p.ModifiedUserID).Editable(false);
        m.Field(p => p.Comment).Editable(true);             
    })
    .Create(update => update.Action("GridNullFunction", "Provider"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("GridNullFunction", "Provider"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("GridNullFunction", "Provider"))
    .ServerOperation(true)
)

)
```

Comment: it still thinks you are in create mode.  this is sign that the Id property for that row is 0 or empty.  need to see your javascript and controller code..

Comment: @JamieD77 Thanks for quick response. The Controller functions which I put for CRUD are the same dummy Action in the Controller. What I intended to do is to do all the CRUD on client side and save the grid information when post the whole form.